# How do I align the decimal place in a DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a customer that doesn't want trailing zeros on a decimal. He wants 1.2 to show as 1.2 and 0.0125 to show as 0.0125 with no trailing zeros. But he also wants the decimal points to line up in the column. I haven't the foggiest on how I could do that or even if it can be done.

**UPDATE**

Using the comments and suggestions...

My Custom Control:

```
public sealed partial class BufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public BufferedDataGridView()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My Windows Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BufferedDataGridView _dgv = new BufferedDataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<NumberList> numbers = LoadSampleData();

        Font font = new Font("Consolas", 8, FontStyle.Regular);

        _dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font = font;

        _dgv.CellFormatting += Dgv_CellFormatting;

        _dgv.CellDoubleClick += Dgv_CellDoubleClick;

        Controls.Add(_dgv);

        _dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        bindingSource1.DataSource = numbers;
        _dgv.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void Dgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell =
            _dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        string stringValue = cell.Value.ToString();

        decimal value;
        decimal.TryParse(stringValue, out value);

        Debug.WriteLine("decimal value: " + value);
    }

    private static IList<NumberList> LoadSampleData()
    {
        NumberList number1 = new NumberList {Number = 100.25M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        NumberList number2 = new NumberList {Number = 3.128M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        NumberList number3 = new NumberList {Number = 10.2M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        NumberList number4 = new NumberList {Number = .1257M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        NumberList number5 = new NumberList {Number = 1000M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        NumberList number6 = new NumberList {Number = .0128M.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};

        IList<NumberList> numbers = new List<NumberList>();

        numbers.Add(number1);
        numbers.Add(number2);
        numbers.Add(number3);
        numbers.Add(number4);
        numbers.Add(number5);
        numbers.Add(number6);

        return numbers;
    }

    private void Dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell =
                _dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

            string originalCell = e.Value.ToString();

            string reformattedCell = FormatCell(originalCell);

            cell.Value = reformattedCell;
        }
    }


    private static string FormatCell(string originalCell)
    {
        if (originalCell.Contains("."))
        {
            string wholeNumber = originalCell.Split('.')[0];

            string decimalNumber = originalCell.Split('.')[1];

            return wholeNumber.PadLeft(7) + "." + decimalNumber;
        }
        return originalCell.PadLeft(7);
    }
}
```

My Number List Class:

```
public class NumberList
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

I had to make the Class property type string and not decimal, and then parse out the value. Does anyone have a suggestion so I can have the Number List Class use decimal type and not string?

Comment: try change displayed value in `CellFormatting` event: (right)pad string value with spaces

Comment: For this to work it is __highly__ recommended to use a __fixed-size__ font like `Consolas`. Then it will work just as in your console application. It will also look nice as not only the decimal points but the digits themselves will line up! - If you __need__ to use a proportional font you should a) determine the length of the 1st part by using `MeasureString` or some other text measurement method and then add spaces (or better yet `n-spaces`) as needed and also b) put a __price tag__ on this effort. I think I could do it in __one man hour__, so make it at least __two man days__!

Comment: If your column is read-only, one possible roundabout option is to use three columns (integer, decimal-point, decimal).  Set integer column to right-aligned and then bind to your split on `'.'` (or `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` if you are globalizing).  If read-write, you will need events to capture the keypress of `.` (or `,`) and focus the next field.

Comment: You will also probably need an arbitrary maximum number of decimal places...